# Update data.tables inside a list

Tags: r, list, function, data.table

I want to apply a function to a list of data.tables to update a couple of columns. The problem is that the  the data.tables inside the list end up all with the same changes. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
data("mtcars")
setDT(mtcars)


# Replicate dts in a list
dt_list <- rep(list(mtcars), 4)

# My Function
  update_dt <- function(i){ 
                            # new column
                            dt_list[[i]][, newcol := i]

                            # Updating column
                            dt_list[[i]][, mpg:= mpg + ((i-1)* 100)]
                            }

# Apply function
lapply(X= 1:length(dt_list), FUN= update_dt)
```

In this case, the all data.tables inside my `dt_list` end up identical

Comment: `replicate(4, copy(mtcars))`. When you turn it into a DT, it has a single memory reference, and it assumes by-reference semantics, so all variables point to the same memory location.

Comment: Or `rep` first, then `lapply(dt_list, setDT)`.

Comment: Or `rbindlist(dt_list, idcol = "newcol")[, mpg := mpg + (newcol - 1)*100][]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @r2evans , By replicating the data.table, you're just replicating the reference. Instead, replicate the data.frame and set it as data.table as part of your function.

```
library(data.table)
data("mtcars")



# Replicate dts in a list
dt_list <- rep(list(mtcars), 4)


# My Function
update_dt <- function(i){ 
  setDT(dt_list[[i]]) # Set as DT inside function
  # new column
  dt_list[[i]][, newcol := i]

  # Updating column
  dt_list[[i]][, mpg:= mpg + ((i-1)* 100)]
}

# Apply function
lapply(X= 1:length(dt_list), FUN= update_dt)
```